# Resize images in UIWebView to viewport size

Tags: iphone, image, uiwebview

I'm displaying HTML with some images inside a UIWebView in my iPhone App. 
When the images are wider than the viewport of the iPhone I get horizontal scrollers which I don't want because its mostly about the text not the images.

Is there a way to resize images displayed inside the UIWebView according to the width (best: even if the device is rotated)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want the maximum width to be the width of the webView, use the max-width CSS property.

> max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;

Comment: Thanks! Added it to my CSS file. I first thought there would be a setting for the UIWebView to keep images from being wider. This is just simple!

Comment: I tried to add it: NSString *cssString = @"<style type='text/css'>max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;</style>"; but it doesn't make any influence

Comment: @Odelya `<style type='text/css'>img { max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; }</style>` worked for me.

Comment: I had to use 100%% instead of 100% because it was counting it as a conversion specifier. Rest was the same..

Answer (score 5):

If the image is inside a UIWebView you could try using css to size them to 100%?

Something like . . .

```
<img style="width:100%" src="..." />
```

DISCLAIMER: I don't have XCode handy to test that but it should work! You'll have to try it for yourself!

Comment: It's not as good as the accepted answer though - my answer always scales up to full width; what about if your images are smaller? - the accepted answer only scales down images that are too large. (And hardcoding attributes in HTML is considered bad practice!)

Comment: @deanWombourne I tried the solution - I added it to the HTML NSString *cssString = @"<style type='text/css'>max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;</style>"; but still the images are bigger

Comment: This also works: <img style="max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto" src="..." />

Answer (score 0):

for AutoHeightWebView you can put in **customStyle** props max-width:

```
<AutoHeightWebView
customStyle={`
        * {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
      `}
```