# resize the frame in uiwebviews

Tags: iphone

How to resize the image frame in the UIwebview but i put setscalepages fit it shrinks the images and the content sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

[Resize images in UIWebView to viewport size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676279/resize-images-in-uiwebview-to-viewport-size)