# how to fit the image perfectly in the webview thats is parsed from <content:encoded> Wordpress rssfeed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rss

I m parsing this rss feed ("http://rss.marshillchurch.org/mhcvision") which is a wordpress blog and displaying it in tableview .clicking on the tableview row takes you to a detail view.I m parsing the following tags  where the detail view contains the data from the content:encoded...the problem is the image size is too big to fit the detail view screen,which leads to horizontal scrolling...how to fit the image perfectly in the iphone  webview 320X220...any help is much appreciated below is the image and the code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.itemTitle.text=[item objectForKey:@"title"];


[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[item objectForKey:@"content:encoded"] baseURL:nil];
    [self.itemSummary setClipsToBounds:YES];
    self.itemSummary.opaque=NO;
    self.itemSummary.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways:

The first (easiest) is enabling the `Scales Page to Fit`  property in the IB attributes inspector of the webView.

The second is processing the html code of the entry and adjusting the width of the image to make it fit your screen.

I don't know much of HTML (Correct me if I'm wrong) but, after googling a little bit found that this can be accomplished using:

```
<img src="yourImagePath" width="100%" alt="">
```

Comment: i tried the first method...its like the entire page got shrunk...cud u explain the second method in detail...

Comment: You have to find the <img> tag in the html you parsed from the feed and modify it

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any code for that, maybe you could post the HTML you receive in another answer and ask how can you modify the image to fit the screen size

Comment: Yes, that's the html you have to study and modify for your needs

Comment: Check this answer for implementing the 100% width for the image.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676279/resize-images-in-uiwebview-to-viewport-size